# Submit button works but doesn't show page refresh in Production server but works fine in ITG server and Local Server(Asp.net using c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Have ASP.Net Submit button which is used to fetch the data from SQL Server and display the result in the grid. Now it works as expected but it neither shows progress bar nor page refresh.This problem is happening only production server and works properly in ITG and local server. I searched everywhere for answer but didn't find. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you checked browser console for errors when you are browsing your production website.

Comment: Yeah.. I have 4 'failed to load resources error' ..But this is there in ITG as well but there it works.

Comment: are you fetching the data from server with normal postback or some sort of ajax call?? show us some code.

Comment: Normal postback..Using web service.

Comment: Post you code.its almost impossible to imagine your scenario.

Comment: If nothing helps, try to rebuild your page from a newly created page. Maybe a reference is not hooked correctly, or the pages required resources are not published correctly. Also you could try to clean your project and your production setup (take a backup before!). Or restart the production webserver.

Comment: Ok Gagan.Thank you so much.